rclone: howto exclude one specified directory AND every subdirectory with certain name
I have the following directory structure:
├───dir1
│   ├───subdir1
│   ├───subdir2
│   └───subdir3
├───dir1 2
│   ├───subdir1
│   ├───subdir2
│   └───subdir3
├───dir2
│   ├───dir1
│   ├───dir12
│   ├───subdir2
│   └───subdir3
└───dir3
    ├───dir1
    └───dir13

every directory and the subdirectories contain three files file0, file1, file2.
I want to filter dir1 in root (but not dir1 2) and every subdir2
I tried this command:
rclone.exe ls --dump filters -vv --exclude "{/dir1/**,subdir2/**}" "src"
--- start filters ---
--- File filter rules ---
- (^|/)(/dir1/.*|subdir2/.*)$
--- Directory filter rules ---
- (^|/)(/dir1/.*|subdir2/.*)$
--- end filters ---
2024/05/13 10:54:55 DEBUG : rclone: Version "v1.66.0" starting with parameters ["rclone.exe" "ls" "--dump" "filters" "-vv" "--exclude" "{/dir1/**,subdir2/**}" "src"]
...
        0 dir3/file0
        0 dir3/file1
2024/05/13 10:54:55 DEBUG : dir1 2/subdir2: Excluded
        0 dir3/file2
2024/05/13 10:54:55 DEBUG : dir2/subdir2: Excluded
        0 dir1 2/file0
2024/05/13 10:54:55 DEBUG : dir1/subdir2: Excluded
        0 dir1 2/file1
        0 dir1 2/file2
        0 dir2/file0
        0 dir2/file1
        0 dir2/file2
        0 dir1 2/subdir1/file0
        0 dir1 2/subdir1/file1
        0 dir1 2/subdir1/file2
        0 dir3/dir13/file0
        0 dir3/dir13/file1
        0 dir3/dir13/file2
        0 dir1/file0
        0 dir1/file1
        0 dir1/file2
        0 dir3/dir1/file0
        0 dir3/dir1/file1
        0 dir3/dir1/file2
        0 dir1 2/subdir3/file0
        0 dir1 2/subdir3/file1
        0 dir1 2/subdir3/file2
        0 dir2/subdir3/file0
        0 dir2/subdir3/file1
        0 dir2/subdir3/file2
        0 dir2/dir1/file0
        0 dir2/dir1/file1
        0 dir2/dir1/file2
        0 dir2/dir12/file0
        0 dir2/dir12/file1
        0 dir2/dir12/file2
        0 dir1/subdir1/file0
        0 dir1/subdir1/file1
        0 dir1/subdir1/file2
        0 dir1/subdir3/file0
        0 dir1/subdir3/file1
        0 dir1/subdir3/file2

subdir2 is excluded but dir1 not.

{<full_path_to>/src/dir1/**,subdir2/**} or
{/dir1/,subdir2/**} doesn't work either.
{dir1/,subdir2/**} filters every dir1.

Maybe I'm blind, but I didn't find the solution in https://rclone.org/filtering/#directory_filter.
What should I give to the pattern-list filter to achive the desired output?

I found a solution:
 rclone.exe ls --dump filters -vv --exclude /dir1/** --exclude "{subdir2/**}" "src"
--- start filters ---
--- File filter rules ---
- ^dir1/.*$
- (^|/)(subdir2/.*)$
--- Directory filter rules ---
- ^dir1/.*$
- (^|/)(subdir2/.*)$
--- end filters ---
...
2024/05/13 15:59:12 DEBUG : dir1: Excluded
        0 dir3/file0
        0 dir3/file1
        0 dir3/file2
2024/05/13 15:59:12 DEBUG : dir1 2/subdir2: Excluded
        0 dir1 2/file0
2024/05/13 15:59:12 DEBUG : dir2/subdir2: Excluded
        0 dir1 2/file1
        0 dir1 2/file2
...
        0 dir3/dir1/file0
        0 dir3/dir1/file1
        0 dir3/dir1/file2


The directory filter rule should be placed in a separate --exclude, it doesn't work in pattern-list between curly braces.
